# How quick search folder/file only by letters only?

Tags: dired

Emacs 26.1, Window 10

If I want to find in dired mode some file/folder I :

1. `C-s`
2. Input file/folder name

Here result:

[image]

OK. It's work. 
But it slow. 
Is it possible to search file/folder only by input file/folder names. Without `C-s` operation.

Is it possible?

Comment: The question is not too clear. Are you asking for behavior like `C-s`, to go to a file name in Dired by typing text that matches only against the file name, but in a way that is faster than `C-s`? Or would something like `find-name-dired` help you? Consider showing a recipe of what actions you want to make and what result you want to achieve. It's also possible that the way you're using `C-s` causes poor performance. Also, you can filter the files shown in Dired, in case your listing is very long.

Comment: @Drew I need go to a file name in Dired by typing text that matches only against the file name.

Comment: Then `C-s` (or `C-M-s` is all I'm aware of. But again, you might be able to speed things up by filtering your Dired buffer - fewer file names to match means quicker, in general.

Comment: @Drew And how I can use filter in dired mode? Is I need install external package.  Or it's out of box?

Comment: `C-x d foo*.el bar*` etc. is one way. `dired-omit-mode` is another way. `M-: (dired "foo" LIST-OF-FILE-NAMES)` is another - the files can be in any directories. If you use Dired+ then the last is simplified interactively as `diredp-dired-for-files`, bound to `C-x D F`. Start with `C-x M-o` (`dired-omit-mode`).

Comment: Another question is why it is slow. Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find out what is slowing down search here.

Comment: @Drew Is it possible to do "C-x d" interactively? E.g. when input foo*. to show ON FLY  all files/directories start by "foo" . To not need press ENTER. Is it possible?

Comment: If you mean show the glob matches for `foo*` before hitting `RET` then no. But if you use a library that matches with regexps, such as [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then yes: `C-x d foo.*` (note the `.` - this is a regexp, not a glob pattern). Even with vanilla Emacs you can set `completion-styles` to include regexp-matching style, then use `TAB` completion to see the matches.